# Batch processing via REST service

Tags: rest

Are there any best practices for performing BATCH operations via REST for POST, PUT, PATCH verbs?

The current paradigm I am following is that the JSON payload is specified in the body for all 3 operations:

a) POST to return the location of the created resource
b) PUT / PATCH return a 201 if the update is successful

For a batch operation, I intend to accept a collection of JSON objects in the payload body but am trying to figure what to return to the client.

While processing the batch, the operation may succeed for some of the items but might fail for others.

Taking this into account, my take is that the best thing to do is to return a collection of objects indicating the Success/Failure status of each item from the payload.

But this deviates from my paradigm outlined in (a) and (b) above.

Instead, does it make sense to return an identifier representing an ID of the Batch operation itself to the client?

The client would then issue a subsequent GET to get the result of the operation it requested.

Does this approach sound reasonable? If so, does it make sense to block the client on the subsequent GET if the operation hasn't completed OR does it make sense to always return the most current state i.e. a collection of responses for each of the items that the client requested to process.

Ideas/Thoughts/Suggestions?

Since REST is an architectural style with no necessarily clear "guidelines" and no
mandate on how the actions for HTTP verbs should be implements, clearly there is no right or wrong answer here.

I am looking for a solution that is elegant, natural and intuitive.

Comment: REST is not a "guideline". It's an architectural style.

Comment: Does every resource need batch operations, or just one?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your task?

Comment: @Eric: I agree that REST is an architectural style. The use of the word "guideline" in this context is primarily because I have seen varying implementations of how the actions for HTTP  verbs are implemented. There is no clear answer as to how should you treat a PATCH operation that accepts an array for instance. Should you return a collection of results or should you return a single result? IMHO it would be confusing to say that the batch failed if some operations succeeded. How would you indicate which items were processed successfully?

Comment: @AbhijeetPatel from RFC 5789, section 2, paragraph 6: "The server MUST apply the entire set of changes atomically [...]" There is also RFC 6902 for JSON formatting for a PATCH which handles arrays.

Answer (score 4):

REST operations are supposed to be atomic as seen from the outside. That is, if one part of the request fails, then the whole state of the server should revert to the pre-request state and a 4xx or 5xx response returned (so, for example, the request could be repeated in whole without ill effects if it failed the first time). This however has nothing to do with batch operations per se—such a request could be any kind of request.

Batch operations violate a different REST constraint, that of the uniform interface (defined by HTTP's methods and their operation upon a resource at the specified URL).

If you want to do batch operations, give up on trying to call your API RESTful, because you have already lost out on the benefits that REST imparts, and are just lying to yourself.

If you want to retain those benefits, give up on batch operations.

Comment: Creating a batch operation that is idempotent is  easily solved with implementation. As for not calling the API RESTful because there is a batch operation seems overly pragmatic. You just need to think differently about the resource that is being created, in this case the new resource is a batch operation.

Comment: @Leon If you 'create' a resource at /batch-ops/12 and can query that resource to get the current state of the operation, then yes, that is RESTful. If you are just posting to /batch/make-new-users then no, it's not REST, it's RPC.

Answer (score 2):

REST is an architectural style.

I implement APIs to always return the result of what was updated. So in the case of a POST it will return the created entity, with PATCH and PUT it will return the updated entity.

Depending on the batch size I would either return an array of what was processed, or alternatively an array of identifiers of what was processed.

If the batch operation is long running return an identifier for the batch, but make it painfully clear that the endpoint is different from other endpoints

ex. if you create a user by posting to
http://somesite.com/users

send batch requests to 
http://somesite.com/batch/users

On a get return the status of the batch operation while it is still running, on complete return an array of record that were updated.

The most important thing is consistency, whatever you choose, always follow the same approach with batch operation throughout the system.

Comment: REST is *not* a "guideline". It's an architectural style.